# Quick way to extract CSS style attributes from html elements

Tags: python, selenium, webkit, html-parsing, phantomjs

For machine learning purposes, i have an html page as input, to extract all the style attributes of all DOM elements. So, here is my preliminary code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

start = time.time()
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('example page')
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[not(child::*)]") #select only leaf nodes
l = {}
css_properties=("line-height", "text-align","font-size", "font-style")

for i in elements:
    if i.text:
        #print time.time() - end_dl
        if i.text not in l:
            l[i.text] = {}
        for el in css_properties:
            l[i.text][el] = str(i.value_of_css_property(el))
            l[i.text]["text_length"] = len(i.text)
```

The problem is that this code is taking too long to parse my features (~8s). Can anyone think in a faster way to do this?

Comment: I recommend [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead

Comment: Use something like `lxml` which is pretty fast at parsing XML/HTML. Anyway, before trying this you should make sure that it isn't the calls to `PhantomJS` that take the bulk of time(which probably *is* the problem).

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. In my case, i cant use beautifulsoup because i need style attributes that are located in the css file, like font-size

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the parsing step that's taking so long?

If so, here are a few options...

1. Try BeautifulSoup4 for parsing the DOM.
2. Deploy on a cloud server with faster hardware. You could use amazon EC2 or digitalocean for something that charges by the hour.
3. Deploy on a distributed system.

Comment: The problem is that BeautifulSoup wont take the CSS in consideration. And i need to extract features like font-size, for example.

Comment: Distribute the job then?